# How to load values into multiple text areas based on value from first column in spreadsheet- Google Script?

Tags: arrays, listbox, google-apps-script

I need to create an application in Google Script that can read values from a spreadsheet and load those values into text areas based on the value of the first column. For example, in the first column I have NickNames, on the second first name, on the third last name, on the fourth stop date. I have managed to load the nicknames into a listbox using getRange. But I need to know how to load the adjacent values (first, last, stop date) according to NickName into text areas. After the click of a button these values will be updated without creating a new record. Let me know. It would be of great help.

Here is the code I have so far. I need to load values into the corresponding text fields based on the nickname chosen from the dropdown box:

```
function doGet() {
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
var abspanel= app.createAbsolutePanel();
var stackpanel=app.createStackPanel();
var grid3=app.createGrid(12,12).setId('grd3');
var loadbtn= app.createButton('Load Employee Data');
var selectlbl=app.createLabel('Select Employee');
var active= SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Ai21cbl').getSheetByName('testing');
var endrow= active.getLastRow()-1;
var emplist=app.createListBox().setId('emps').setName('elist');

var emprange= active.getRange('A2:F100').getValues().sort();
 for(var i=0; i<emprange.length; i++){
   emplist.addItem(emprange[i][0])
 }

var efirstlabel=app.createLabel('First').setId('elabel');
var efname=app.createTextArea().setId('efirst').setHeight('20px').setName('efst');
var elastlabel=app.createLabel('Last').setId('ellabel');
var elname=app.createTextArea().setId('elast').setHeight('20px').setName('elst');
var enicklabel=app.createLabel('NickName').setId('enlabel');
var enname= app.createTextArea().setId('enick').setHeight('20px').setName('enk');
var eattlabel= app.createLabel('Employee Attribute').setId('ealabel').setHeight('20px');
var eatt1='TLYDYE'
var eatt2='TLYDNE'
var eatt3='TLNDYE'
var eatt4='TLNDNE'
var eatt5='CAYDYE'
var eatt6='CAYDNE'
var eatt7='CANDYE'
var eatt8='CANDNE'
var eattlist=app.createListBox().setWidth('120px').setId('eattribute').setName('eattbt')
eattlist.addItem(eatt1);
eattlist.addItem(eatt2);
eattlist.addItem(eatt3);
eattlist.addItem(eatt4);
eattlist.addItem(eatt5);
eattlist.addItem(eatt6);
eattlist.addItem(eatt7);
eattlist.addItem(eatt8);

var estartlabel=app.createLabel('Start Date:');
var estartdate=app.createDateBox().setId('edate');
var estoplabel=app.createLabel('Stop Date:');
var estopdate=app.createDateBox().setId('sdate');
var inlabel=app.createLabel().setId('indexlabel');

//Edit Employee Handler

var loadhandler=app.createServerClickHandler('loadEmp');
loadhandler.addCallbackElement(stackpanel);
loadbtn.addClickHandler(loadhandler);

grid3
.setWidget(1,1,selectlbl)
.setWidget(1,2,emplist)
.setWidget(1,3,loadbtn)
.setWidget(2,1, efirstlabel)
.setWidget(2,2, efname)
.setWidget(2,3, elastlabel)
.setWidget(2,4, elname)
.setWidget(3,1, enicklabel)
.setWidget(3,2, enname)
.setWidget(4,1, eattlabel)
.setWidget(5,1,eattlist)
.setWidget(6,1,estartlabel)
.setWidget(7,1,estartdate)
.setWidget(8,1,estoplabel)
.setWidget(9,1,estopdate)
.setWidget(10,1,inlabel);

stackpanel.add(grid3, 'Edit Employee').setStyleAttribute("text-align", "center")
app.add(abspanel)
app.add(stackpanel)  
return app;
}

function loadEmp(e){
var app=UiApp.getActiveApplication();

app.getElementById('efirst').setValue(e.parameter.elist);

return app;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for someone to develop it for you? This is not the right place to do it. If not, then please add some code of your attempt and where you're having problems.

Comment: Henrique I added the code above. I basically want to load adjacent values from the Nickname selected into text areas after the click of the button. Then with another button be able to update this data in the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess it's easier if when adding each name to the list you add as the value to return the row number instead omitting and have just the name. This way it will be easier (i.e. you won't need to search for it) to reload the values on the `loadEmp` handler. e.g.

```js
function doGet() {
  //... the starting code your already have
  var emprange = active.getDataRange().getValues(); //sorting a matrix doesn't make sense
  //also, it's easier if you sort by the desired column the on the spreadsheet before hand
  for( var i = 1; i < emprange.length; ++i )
    emplist.addItem(emprange[i][0], i); //this 2nd parameter "i" is the return value

  //... rest of your code
}

function loadEmp(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var active = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Ai21cbl').getSheetByName('testing');
  var index = +e.parameter.elist;
  var empdata = active.getRange(index+1, 1, 1, 6).getValues()[0];
  var cols = ['efirst','elast','enick']; //in the same order as in the spreadsheet
  for( var i = 0; i < cols.length; ++i )
    app.getElementById(cols[i]).setValue(empdata[i]);
  return app;
}
```

It's the same thing for the save button, you'll just `setValues` instead of get.

Comment: Henrique. It reads the values but puts them all into one textbox. It does not split the values. Everything is in one textbox separated by comma. In the other textboxes I get the value of undefined. Any idea?

Comment: It's fixed. Forgot to add the brackets for the row, since `getValues` always returns a matrix.

Comment: It works now. But do you know why the datebox does not update with the correct value. I added a change handler to the elist. The values in the firstname lastname change. But the start date and stop date only work at times. I change the employee name in the listbox and sometimes the dates do not update to reflect the cell value. Does this have to do with the type of value? maybe with e.parameter in the index?

Comment: In the code I provided I didn't add anything about dates, I'm assuming you "enhanced" it, right? Anyway, this sounds like an issue for another question, where you can paste your new code, pinpoint the issue, etc.